# Solving issues with dependencies in a NetBeans Maven Project

Tags: java, maven, netbeans

I have a project in NetBeans that uses Maven to download additional dependencies I might need. Yesterday I started getting red underlines on imports that had already existed for months. I made a couple of mistakes that made the problem worse in trying to fix it, I misunderstood how "install local artifact" is used and I think ended up placing some JARs inside other packages.

The long story short of it is that now I have an indeterminate number of packages that have the correct name, but incorrect contents. I tried deleting the project cloning an earlier version, and switching to other branches of the project I have never touched, but the imports still appear to be messed up, so I can only conclude there is a local problem with my computer.

Is there any way to wipe out all the locally installed versions of these packages and re-download them fresh? Its to the point where trying to solve it one problem at a time would eat up multiple days, and since I have a saved copy of the correctly formatted pom.xml for my project, I'd rather just rebuild from there, but I have no idea how to do that, or even if it is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to delete all maven artifacts from your local maven repository: $USER_HOME/.m2
And then refresh the project so it will re-download all dependencies.
You could also just delete those dependencies that are causing problems

Comment: That mostly fixed it. I'm still having trouble with getting it to see one package that is absolutely in the dependencies, I can stare at the class in the dependencies, yet it won't load when I import. Still, it is 90% better, and this package was a problem to import in the first place, so I'm fairly happy.